# How to get list of employees in each department seperated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have tried below one using XML Path but getting error.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Can you correct the below query.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + COUNT(E.EMployeeId) FROM EMployee E WHERE E.DepartmentId IN(SELECT DepartmentId FROM Department) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

Required Output

```
5,7,8,9
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluK in order to avoid error message you should cast your `count` to varchar

Comment: Try my answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

The `COUNT()` Returns `integer` value, you can't merge `int` with `varchar`. So you have to `convert` the value to `char`.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(COUNT(E.EMployeeId) AS VARCHAR) FROM EMployee E WHERE E.DepartmentId IN(SELECT DepartmentId FROM Department) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

Try this answer, If you face any issue, mention in the comments:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentId,
     STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',' + CAST(COUNT(E.EMployeeId) AS VARCHAR) 
            FROM EMployee E 
            WHERE E.DepartmentId IN(SELECT DepartmentId FROM Department) 
                AND E.DepartmentId=T.DepartmentId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ), 1, 1, '') AS id_list
FROM EMployee as T
```

Try this one for, both department and `COUNT()` in Comma separated:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST((DepartmentId)AS VARCHAR) 
FROM(
    SELECT DepartmentId,COUNT(EMployeeId) EMployeeId
    FROM EMployee E 
    WHERE E.DepartmentId IN(SELECT DepartmentId FROM Department) 
    GROUP BY DepartmentId
    )E
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') DepID
    ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST((EMployeeId)AS VARCHAR)
FROM(
    SELECT DepartmentId,COUNT(EMployeeId) EMployeeId
    FROM EMployee E 
    WHERE E.DepartmentId IN(SELECT DepartmentId FROM Department) 
    GROUP BY DepartmentId
    )E
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')EmpCount
```

Comment: Hi dinesh, it' working but giving total employee count. I m looking for employee count in each department separated by comma. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: How can we get list of employee count in each department

Comment: Wait a few minutes, I'll check and tell you...

Comment: To get employee count for each department simply use, 
SELECT DepartmentId, count(*) as cnt
FROM Employee
Group By DepartmentId

Comment: I have tried the same but I was trying to employee count in each department as a list

Comment: Try the updated answer, hope this helps you